# Find inverse of PHP function

Tags: php

Since i'm more of a "noob" at PHP than i'd hope, Is it possible to inverse the following function for example:

```
public function baseID($resourceid){
    $rid = $resourceid;
    $version = 0;

    while ($rid > 16777216){
        $version++;
        if ($version == 1){
            //the constant applied to all items
            $rid -= 1342177280;
        }elseif ($version == 2){
            //the value added to the first updated version
            $rid -= 50331648;
        }else{
            //the value added on all subsequent versions
            $rid -= 16777216;
        }
    }

    //$returnable = array('baseID'=>$rid,'version'=>$version);
    return $rid;
}
```

Would it be possible to input the "baseID" and return a "resourceID" instead of the current way ?

I apologize if this is the wrong place to be asking such question

Comment: I think this is a Maths question.

Comment: It is not reverse engineering. It is about making the inverse or reciprocal function of your `baseID` function (which probably is not bijective, so has no well defined inverse)

Comment: You're asking for the inverse function, not reverse engineering.  If each baseID can only be derived from a single resource ID, then yes, it's possible to create an inverse function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This function only works to a limited range, however at a certain point the resource IDs will start returning the same results.**

```
public function resourceID($baseid){
    $bid = $baseid;
    $version = 0;

    while ($bid <= 16777216){
        ++$version;

        if ($version === 1){
            $bid += 1342177280;
        } elseif ($version === 2){
            $bid += 50331648;
        } else {
            $bid += 16777216;
        }
    }

    return $bid;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is the inverse of the function posted by the OP

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I haven't tested it but it looks fine to me. Would you care to point out where the error is?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: The function isn't bijective, just like `f(x) = x^2`. Given `f(x) = 9`, you can't tell whether `x` was `3` or `-3`.

Comment: @Blender I stand corrected. Things I learned last year in discrete math in first-year university are starting to come back to me. Thanks :P (Upvoted your answer.)

Comment: `echo $f->resourceID('164469')."<br/>"; echo $f->baseID('1342341749');`  produces the alternates as expected.

Comment: @CurtisCrewe It won't work for numbers greater than 1409286144 I believe.

Comment: @CurtisCrewe: No, your function just isn't invertable. `baseID(1409286144)` and `baseID(1426063360)` return the same number, so you can't determine which one you plugged into the function.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 it won't be numbers more than 500,000 that i'll be converting anyway

Comment: @CurtisCrewe: If your numbers are all less than 500,000, then your function won't anything to the numbers at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Your function returns the same value for all `rid`s that are of the form:

```
5 * 2^28 + (3 + n) * 2^24
```

Where `n` is a positive integer.

```
>>> baseID(5 * 2**28 + (3 + 1) * 2**24)
    16777216
>>> baseID(5 * 2**28 + (3 + 2) * 2**24)
    16777216
>>> baseID(5 * 2**28 + (3 + 3) * 2**24)
    16777216
```

So given just `16777216`, you won't be able to determine what went into your function.